# IE Bug? or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I've got the following code:

**CSS**

```
ul li {
    width: 100%;
    padding 0;
    margin 0;   
}
    ul.step li{
    list-style-image: url(TID05.png);
    background: #5E5E5E;
}

    ul.substep li{
    list-style-image: url(TID07.png);
background: #A6A6A6;
}

table{
table-layout: fixed; 
width: 100%;
}
td.bgImage{
    width:15px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(TID09.png);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="step">
<li>1</li>
<ul class="substep">
    <li>1</li>
        <table><tr><td class="bgImage"></td><td>Lorem</td><td>ipsum</td><td>foo</td><td>bar</tr></tr></table>
    <li>2</li>
        <table><tr><td class="bgImage"></td><td>Lorem</td><td>ipsum</td><td>foo</td><td>bar</tr></tr></table>
    <li>3</li>
        <table><tr><td class="bgImage"></td><td>Lorem</td><td>ipsum</td><td>foo</td><td>bar</tr></tr></table>
        <table><tr><td class="bgImage"></td><td>Lorem</td><td>ipsum</td><td>foo</td><td>bar</tr></tr></table>
    <li>4</li>
        <table><tr><td class="bgImage"></td><td>Lorem</td><td>ipsum</td><td>foo</td><td>bar</tr></tr></table>
        <table><tr><td class="bgImage"></td><td>Lorem</td><td>ipsum</td><td>foo</td><td>bar</tr></tr></table>
        <table><tr><td class="bgImage"></td><td>Lorem</td><td>ipsum</td><td>foo</td><td>bar</tr></tr></table>
        <table><tr><td class="bgImage"></td><td>Lorem</td><td>ipsum</td><td>foo</td><td>bar</tr></tr></table>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

[image: Browser output]

I want the same result on Internet Explorer as i have on Firefox. Can anybody help?
Is something wrong in my HTML code? or is there a bug in Internet Explorer?

Comment: Can you show us your full HTML? Or possibly link to the site or a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? Also, every one of your `table` elements have two `</tr>` at the end of each row.

Comment: In this case, I would say IE has got it right :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant use any tags outside the li tag.

add span tag to make the numbers as heading and write the css accordingly.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="step">
    <li><span>1</span></li>
<ul class="substep">
    <li><span>1</span>
        <table><tr><td class="bgImage"></td><td>Lorem</td><td>ipsum</td><td>foo</td><td>bar</tr></tr></table></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul li {
        width: 100%;
        padding 0;
        margin 0;   
    }
        ul.step li{
        list-style-image: url(TID05.png);
        background: none;
    }
        ul.step li span{
        list-style-image: url(TID05.png);
        background: #5E5E5E; display:block
    }

        ul.substep li{
        list-style-image: url(TID07.png);
    background: none;
    }
       ul.substep li span{
        list-style-image: url(TID07.png);
    background: #A6A6A6; display:block
    }

    table{
    table-layout: fixed; 
    width: 100%;
    }
    td.bgImage{
        width:15px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-image: url(TID09.png);
    }​
```

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/WCqLh/2/

This give same result in IE 7+ and chrome

Comment: Works fine! Thank you. I didn't realize that can't use the table tag within the ul tag.

Comment: @Sammy46 u r welcome. not only table tag, you can't use anything outside the li tag coz it is not valid,everything should be in the li tag. Also remove that extra </tr> at the end of the each table.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9zHCZ/1/ that's my solution. I added additional li tags because otherwise in IE my Icons get positioned in the middle of the list-element. not at the beginning like Firefox does it. (see my screenshot in the Question)

Comment: The HTML is still broken. You have an `ul` tag inside an `ul` tag.

Comment: That code is only sample, you can find continued code in the fiddle

Answer (score 3):

Your HTML markup is broken. When you put things in a list, it should go inside the `li` elements:

```
<ul class="step">
  <li>1
    <ul class="substep">
      <li>1
        <table><tr><td class="bgImage"></td><td>Lorem</td><td>ipsum</td><td>foo</td><td>bar</tr></table>
      </li>
      <li>2
        <table><tr><td class="bgImage"></td><td>Lorem</td><td>ipsum</td><td>foo</td><td>bar</tr></table>
      </li>
      <li>3
        <table><tr><td class="bgImage"></td><td>Lorem</td><td>ipsum</td><td>foo</td><td>bar</tr></table>
        <table><tr><td class="bgImage"></td><td>Lorem</td><td>ipsum</td><td>foo</td><td>bar</tr></table>
      </li>
      <li>4
        <table><tr><td class="bgImage"></td><td>Lorem</td><td>ipsum</td><td>foo</td><td>bar</tr></table>
        <table><tr><td class="bgImage"></td><td>Lorem</td><td>ipsum</td><td>foo</td><td>bar</tr></table>
        <table><tr><td class="bgImage"></td><td>Lorem</td><td>ipsum</td><td>foo</td><td>bar</tr></table>
        <table><tr><td class="bgImage"></td><td>Lorem</td><td>ipsum</td><td>foo</td><td>bar</tr></table>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Typical for broken HTML is htat browsers will use different ways of trying to fix the markup. Some browsers tend to add more elements, while others tend to rearrange the elements.

Tip: Use the [W3C HTML Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/) to check your code.

Comment: +1 I caught the repeated tablerow closing tags but missed this; wow.

Comment: @JonathanSampson: That I did miss. I removed the duplicate closing tags also. That has less of a risk to cause problems, but correct is better than not. :)

Answer (score 2):

`<ul>` can only have `<li>` children. You have `<table>` children of a `<ul>` and a `<ul>` child of a `<ul>`.

Comment: Well, you can have a <ul> in a <ul>, as long as you keep the symantic right. But indeed, I would get rid of the table part and use floats.

Comment: @DijkeMark a nested `ul` must be inside an `li`, it cannot be a direct child of a `ul`

Comment: @DijkeMark: According to the spec, an `ul` element can only have `li` elements as childrden: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-ul-element.html#the-ul-element

Answer (score 2):

Like Alohci said, one very likely problem is that you have `table`s within your `ul`s.

Something like this would be more acceptable:

```
<ul class="step">
<li>1
<ul class="substep">
    <li>1
        <table><tr><td class="bgImage"></td><td>Lorem</td><td>ipsum</td><td>foo</td><td>bar</td></tr></table>
    </li>
    <li>2
        <table><tr><td class="bgImage"></td><td>Lorem</td><td>ipsum</td><td>foo</td><td>bar</td></tr></table>
    </li>
    <li>3
        <table><tr><td class="bgImage"></td><td>Lorem</td><td>ipsum</td><td>foo</td><td>bar</td></tr></table>
        <table><tr><td class="bgImage"></td><td>Lorem</td><td>ipsum</td><td>foo</td><td>bar</td></tr></table>
    </li>
    <li>4
        <table><tr><td class="bgImage"></td><td>Lorem</td><td>ipsum</td><td>foo</td><td>bar</td></tr></table>
        <table><tr><td class="bgImage"></td><td>Lorem</td><td>ipsum</td><td>foo</td><td>bar</td></tr></table>
        <table><tr><td class="bgImage"></td><td>Lorem</td><td>ipsum</td><td>foo</td><td>bar</td></tr></table>
        <table><tr><td class="bgImage"></td><td>Lorem</td><td>ipsum</td><td>foo</td><td>bar</td></tr></table>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

You are also trying to close a bunch of `td`s with `tr`s, and a `ul` within a `ul` which I've also addressed above.

Answer (score 1):

```
Write your HTML as - 

<ul class="step">
<li>
    <div>1</div>
    <ul class="substep">
    <li>
        <div>1</div>
        <table><tr><td class="bgImage"></td><td>Lorem</td><td>ipsum</td><td>foo</td><td>bar</tr></tr></table>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>2</div>
        <table><tr><td class="bgImage"></td><td>Lorem</td><td>ipsum</td><td>foo</td><td>bar</tr></tr></table>
    </li>        

    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```